# How to Add to an Element, Creating it First If Needed

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to add elements to an element, creating it first if it doesn't already exist.

My desired final result, after adding ABC and DEF, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Q/>
  <B>
    <string>ABC</string>
    <string>DEF</string>
  </B>
<A>
```

I thought that the following would accomplish this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Insert a B element if it doesn't exist. -->
  <xsl:template match="A[not(B)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        <B/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="B">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <string>ABC</string>
      <string>DEF</string>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I start with the following, in which <B> already exists, it works fine, returning the result above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org
  <Q/>
  <B/>
</A>
```

However, if I don't have a <B>, as in below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org
  <Q/>
</A>
```

then it creates the <B> as below, but doesn't insert ABC and DEF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org
  <Q/>
  <B/>
</A>
```

So, what am I missing?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <!-- Identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Insert a B element with string elements if it doesn't exist. -->
    <xsl:template match="A[not(B)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <B>
                <xsl:call-template name="add-strings"/>
            </B>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Add string elements to existing B if missing -->
    <xsl:template match="B[not(string)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="add-strings"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Add string elements to caller -->
    <xsl:template name="add-strings">
        <string>ABC</string>
        <string>DEF</string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the sub tags of B too when B does not exist, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Insert a B element if it doesn't exist. -->
  <xsl:template match="A[not(B)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        <B>
           <string>ABC</string>
          <string>DEF</string>
       </B>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="B">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <string>ABC</string>
      <string>DEF</string>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<A>
  <Q/>
</A>
<A>
  <Q/>
  <B/>
</A>
</root>
```

this gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <A>
        <Q/>
        <B>
            <string>ABC</string>
            <string>DEF</string>
        </B>
    </A>
    <A>
        <Q/>
        <B>
            <string>ABC</string>
            <string>DEF</string>
        </B>
    </A>
</root>
```

Comment: Well, that seems kinda' lame (of XSLT, not you).  Isn't there a way to say to do one rule, and then another?

Comment: That requires two passes; one XSLT will only run through input nodes once, only outputting and not reading output nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Empo's answer was very close, but if <B> already contained <string> elements, the new <string>s weren't added.  I made two minor changes, which solved that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Identity transform. -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Insert a B element with string elements if it doesn't exist. -->
  <xsl:template match="A[not(B)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <B>
        <xsl:call-template name="add-strings"/>
      </B>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Add string elements to existing B element. -->
  <xsl:template match="B">  <!-- Whether there are <string>s or not. -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>  <!-- Keep existing <string>s. -->
      <xsl:call-template name="add-strings"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Add string elements to caller. -->
  <xsl:template name="add-strings">
    <string>ABC</string>
    <string>DEF</string>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Details apart (not clearly exposed in your question) the solution to your problem is given by named template.